# Server side software to do Mail Merge (Data Merge)

Tags: api, sdk

Examples of Client side applications that can do this are MS Word via Mail Merge, Adobe InDesign, and Adobe Acrobat with [Evermap](http://www.evermap.com/automailmerge.asp).

I'm looking for a solution that I can host in my web application, this implies an api or sdk to develop against, that will take a data set, and a pdf template, perform the merge, and serve up the completed document.  I would prefer a rich template language, with formatting, conditions, and iterations over simple token replacement.

Answer (score 1):

## LibreOffice

[LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org) app provides an API available in multiple programming languages such as Java. For access to the API, see [the LibreOffice SDK](http://api.libreoffice.org) (software development kit).

This gives you programmatic ability to call on LibreOffice as a headless service rather as a GUI app. You can command LibreOffice to open template documents and perform a mail-merge operation.

So, for example you could build a web app in [Vaadin](http://www.Vaadin.com/) using pure Java executing on the server side to call on LibreOffice running behind the scene to build your documents.

> [web browser] - [web server] - [Java Servlet container] - [Vaadin web app] - [Java library for LibreOffice API] - [LibreOffice app engine] -[your documents & mail-merge]